# Getting GeoJSON data from Google Map lines

Tags: geojson, google-maps, google-earth, google-maps-api

Can I get the GeoJSON data from this Subway line on Google Maps? [image: A picture of lucknow metro's route]

Comment: can you share the url

Comment: @Mapperz https://www.google.com/maps/place/Red+Line/@26.8462254,80.9692862,26977m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m6!3m5!1s0x399bfc512c9e9a75:0xd6075903439d9c4a!8m2!3d26.8330835!4d80.9315253!16s%2Fg%2F11h11ktz36!5m1!1e2

Answer (score 0):

via

https://www.metrolinemap.com/metro/lucknow/

**Stations** and **Metro Line (Red Route).**

```
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "12765", "stationName": "Alambagh", "stationConnections": "<span class='input-color5'><span title='Red Line' class='color-box5' style='background-color: #FF3333;cursor: help'>Rl</span></span>", "stationUrl": "https://www.metrolinemap.com/station/lucknow/alambagh/" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [80.902445373369, 26.813949222292] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "12766", "stationName": "Alambagh ISBT", "stationConnections": "<span class='input-color5'><span title='Red Line' class='color-box5' style='background-color: #FF3333;cursor: help'>Rl</span></span>", "stationUrl": "https://www.metrolinemap.com/station/lucknow/alambagh-isbt/" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [80.907234406131, 26.818420990751] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "12761", "stationName": "Amausi", "stationConnections": "<span class='input-color5'><span title='Red Line' class='color-box5' style='background-color: #FF3333;cursor: help'>Rl</span></span>", "stationUrl": "https://www.metrolinemap.com/station/lucknow/amausi/" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [80.878749968755, 26.7714961409] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "13215", "stationName": "Badshah Nagar", "stationConnections": "<span class='input-color5'><span title='Red Line' class='color-box5' style='background-color: #FF3333;cursor: help'>Rl</span></span>", "stationUrl": "https://www.metrolinemap.com/station/lucknow/badshah-nagar/" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [80.961066486806, 26.870678520723] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "13217", "stationName": "Bhootnath Market", "stationConnections": "<span class='input-color5'><span title='Red Line' class='color-box5' style='background-color: #FF3333;cursor: help'>Rl</span></span>", "stationUrl": "https://www.metrolinemap.com/station/lucknow/bhootnath-market/" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [80.982306036913, 26.872209119445] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "12769", "stationName": "Charbagh", "stationConnections": "<span class='input-color5'><span title='Red Line' class='color-box5' style='background-color: #FF3333;cursor: help'>Rl</span></span>", "stationUrl": "https://www.metrolinemap.com/station/lucknow/charbagh/" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [80.922991372844, 26.832360356771] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "13208", "stationName": "Chaudhary Charan Singh International Airport", "stationConnections": "<span class='input-color5'><span title='Red Line' class='color-box5' style='background-color: #FF3333;cursor: help'>Rl</span></span>", "stationUrl": "https://www.metrolinemap.com/station/lucknow/chaudhary-charan-singh-international-airport/" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [80.883648995748, 26.766259667028] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "12768", "stationName": "Durgapuri", "stationConnections": "<span class='input-color5'><span title='Red Line' class='color-box5' style='background-color: #FF3333;cursor: help'>Rl</span></span>", "stationUrl": "https://www.metrolinemap.com/station/lucknow/durgapuri/" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [80.915367572114, 26.831979451574] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "13211", "stationName": "Hazratganj", "stationConnections": "<span class='input-color5'><span title='Red Line' class='color-box5' style='background-color: #FF3333;cursor: help'>Rl</span></span>", "stationUrl": "https://www.metrolinemap.com/station/lucknow/hazratganj/" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [80.940485177614, 26.850841516268] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "13209", "stationName": "Hussainganj", "stationConnections": "<span class='input-color5'><span title='Red Line' class='color-box5' style='background-color: #FF3333;cursor: help'>Rl</span></span>", "stationUrl": "https://www.metrolinemap.com/station/lucknow/hussainganj/" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [80.934348077233, 26.838421150996] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "13218", "stationName": "Indira Nagar", "stationConnections": "<span class='input-color5'><span title='Red Line' class='color-box5' style='background-color: #FF3333;cursor: help'>Rl</span></span>", "stationUrl": "https://www.metrolinemap.com/station/lucknow/indira-nagar/" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [80.9909056592, 26.872726255447] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "13214", "stationName": "IT College", "stationConnections": "<span class='input-color5'><span title='Red Line' class='color-box5' style='background-color: #FF3333;cursor: help'>Rl</span></span>", "stationUrl": "https://www.metrolinemap.com/station/lucknow/it-college/" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [80.945607770217, 26.871004031223] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "13212", "stationName": "KD Singh Babu Stadium", "stationConnections": "<span class='input-color5'><span title='Red Line' class='color-box5' style='background-color: #FF3333;cursor: help'>Rl</span></span>", "stationUrl": "https://www.metrolinemap.com/station/lucknow/kd-singh-babu-stadium/" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [80.936838723412, 26.853938490314] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "12763", "stationName": "Krishna Nagar", "stationConnections": "<span class='input-color5'><span title='Red Line' class='color-box5' style='background-color: #FF3333;cursor: help'>Rl</span></span>", "stationUrl": "https://www.metrolinemap.com/station/lucknow/krishna-nagar/" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [80.891705309415, 26.794349490436] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "13216", "stationName": "Lekhraj Market", "stationConnections": "<span class='input-color5'><span title='Red Line' class='color-box5' style='background-color: #FF3333;cursor: help'>Rl</span></span>", "stationUrl": "https://www.metrolinemap.com/station/lucknow/lekhraj-market/" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [80.96945221464, 26.870070544021] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "13213", "stationName": "Lucknow University", "stationConnections": "<span class='input-color5'><span title='Red Line' class='color-box5' style='background-color: #FF3333;cursor: help'>Rl</span></span>", "stationUrl": "https://www.metrolinemap.com/station/lucknow/lucknow-university/" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [80.939576872388, 26.865487908047] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "12767", "stationName": "Mawaiya", "stationConnections": "<span class='input-color5'><span title='Red Line' class='color-box5' style='background-color: #FF3333;cursor: help'>Rl</span></span>", "stationUrl": "https://www.metrolinemap.com/station/lucknow/mawaiya/" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [80.909779886003, 26.82528464832] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "13219", "stationName": "Munshipulia", "stationConnections": "<span class='input-color5'><span title='Red Line' class='color-box5' style='background-color: #FF3333;cursor: help'>Rl</span></span>", "stationUrl": "https://www.metrolinemap.com/station/lucknow/munshipulia/" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [80.995856823464, 26.887903453385] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "13210", "stationName": "Sachivalaya", "stationConnections": "<span class='input-color5'><span title='Red Line' class='color-box5' style='background-color: #FF3333;cursor: help'>Rl</span></span>", "stationUrl": "https://www.metrolinemap.com/station/lucknow/sachivalaya/" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [80.939910849809, 26.841594399437] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "12764", "stationName": "Shringar Nagar", "stationConnections": "<span class='input-color5'><span title='Red Line' class='color-box5' style='background-color: #FF3333;cursor: help'>Rl</span></span>", "stationUrl": "https://www.metrolinemap.com/station/lucknow/shringar-nagar/" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [80.896332099905, 26.80300477286] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "12762", "stationName": "Transport Nagar", "stationConnections": "<span class='input-color5'><span title='Red Line' class='color-box5' style='background-color: #FF3333;cursor: help'>Rl</span></span>", "stationUrl": "https://www.metrolinemap.com/station/lucknow/transport-nagar/" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [80.882630630138, 26.777913010054] } }
]
};
    
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 719, "lineNameLong": "Red Line", "lineNameShort": "Rl", "terminuses": "Chaudhary Charan Singh International Airport - Munshipulia", "lineColor": "#FF3333" }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [[80.883649,26.766260],[80.880004,26.766278],[80.879252,26.766253],[80.878919,26.766250],[80.878671,26.766266],[80.878368,26.766335],[80.878096,26.766442],[80.877954,26.766516],[80.877779,26.766647],[80.877613,26.766790],[80.877448,26.766942],[80.877117,26.767391],[80.877016,26.767663],[80.876955,26.767890],[80.876937,26.768078],[80.876974,26.768413],[80.877056,26.768685],[80.877203,26.768976],[80.877737,26.769817],[80.878750,26.771496],[80.882631,26.777913],[80.884913,26.781961],[80.887186,26.786143],[80.889460,26.790288],[80.891705,26.794349],[80.892945,26.796562],[80.894076,26.798648],[80.895231,26.800808],[80.896332,26.803005],[80.899146,26.808579],[80.900518,26.811310],[80.900722,26.811701],[80.900821,26.811883],[80.900928,26.812063],[80.901137,26.812391],[80.901229,26.812523],[80.901353,26.812698],[80.901505,26.812898],[80.901669,26.813107],[80.901876,26.813355],[80.902445,26.813949],[80.904914,26.816100],[80.905261,26.816419],[80.905427,26.816574],[80.905579,26.816722],[80.906081,26.817236],[80.907234,26.818421],[80.907980,26.819189],[80.908177,26.819401],[80.908250,26.819485],[80.908318,26.819581],[80.908433,26.819775],[80.908553,26.819986],[80.908659,26.820225],[80.908740,26.820455],[80.908802,26.820712],[80.909014,26.821707],[80.909780,26.825285],[80.909970,26.826156],[80.910007,26.826336],[80.910031,26.826533],[80.910033,26.826677],[80.910018,26.826903],[80.909991,26.827105],[80.909935,26.827438],[80.909893,26.827745],[80.909889,26.827926],[80.909840,26.828994],[80.909804,26.829585],[80.909788,26.829818],[80.909782,26.830064],[80.909786,26.830162],[80.909801,26.830255],[80.909818,26.830348],[80.909857,26.830476],[80.909907,26.830586],[80.909970,26.830701],[80.910100,26.830872],[80.910208,26.830976],[80.910380,26.831110],[80.910516,26.831186],[80.910711,26.831269],[80.910843,26.831309],[80.911118,26.831368],[80.911698,26.831469],[80.911995,26.831526],[80.912316,26.831594],[80.912880,26.831715],[80.913535,26.831828],[80.913864,26.831868],[80.914296,26.831900],[80.915368,26.831979],[80.922991,26.832360],[80.923910,26.832405],[80.924697,26.832473],[80.925474,26.832531],[80.927079,26.832612],[80.929463,26.832717],[80.930108,26.832748],[80.930624,26.832761],[80.930813,26.832787],[80.931003,26.832833],[80.931237,26.832895],[80.931403,26.832965],[80.931558,26.833054],[80.931798,26.833236],[80.931918,26.833360],[80.932060,26.833542],[80.932994,26.834961],[80.933381,26.835525],[80.933531,26.835787],[80.933607,26.835927],[80.933660,26.836076],[80.933778,26.836471],[80.934348,26.838421],[80.934475,26.838985],[80.934596,26.839279],[80.934693,26.839450],[80.934909,26.839659],[80.935112,26.839759],[80.935315,26.839840],[80.935700,26.839991],[80.936437,26.840266],[80.937423,26.840629],[80.938334,26.840949],[80.938809,26.841117],[80.939348,26.841334],[80.939911,26.841594],[80.940770,26.842089],[80.941170,26.842320],[80.941612,26.842609],[80.941980,26.842883],[80.942369,26.843205],[80.944302,26.844883],[80.944664,26.845174],[80.945205,26.845650],[80.945821,26.846231],[80.945883,26.846318],[80.945903,26.846481],[80.945880,26.846620],[80.945814,26.846798],[80.945671,26.847072],[80.945589,26.847180],[80.945496,26.847250],[80.944078,26.848221],[80.943542,26.848588],[80.942604,26.849274],[80.941665,26.850026],[80.941134,26.850410],[80.940485,26.850842],[80.938308,26.852280],[80.938094,26.852498],[80.937589,26.853042],[80.936839,26.853938],[80.936302,26.854587],[80.936076,26.854930],[80.935941,26.855244],[80.935881,26.855759],[80.935929,26.856129],[80.936070,26.856409],[80.936201,26.856622],[80.936479,26.857017],[80.936651,26.857300],[80.936758,26.857640],[80.936778,26.857968],[80.936703,26.858362],[80.936592,26.859007],[80.936569,26.859363],[80.936600,26.859528],[80.936679,26.859775],[80.936869,26.860156],[80.937070,26.860457],[80.937517,26.861016],[80.937755,26.861307],[80.937972,26.861656],[80.938168,26.862017],[80.938375,26.862464],[80.939067,26.864105],[80.939577,26.865488],[80.939822,26.866163],[80.939951,26.866644],[80.940047,26.867317],[80.940118,26.867901],[80.940212,26.868533],[80.940409,26.869528],[80.940567,26.870258],[80.940694,26.870623],[80.940839,26.870790],[80.941006,26.870970],[80.941279,26.871132],[80.941599,26.871205],[80.941919,26.871249],[80.942336,26.871195],[80.942989,26.871064],[80.943330,26.871061],[80.943852,26.871037],[80.945608,26.871004],[80.948818,26.870904],[80.949234,26.870893],[80.950927,26.870901],[80.953348,26.870841],[80.954803,26.870798],[80.955325,26.870771],[80.956029,26.870686],[80.957760,26.870650],[80.958860,26.870600],[80.959510,26.870607],[80.961066,26.870679],[80.961359,26.870706],[80.962226,26.870830],[80.962830,26.870867],[80.963257,26.870847],[80.965533,26.870657],[80.966352,26.870575],[80.967611,26.870330],[80.968725,26.870100],[80.969056,26.870057],[80.969452,26.870071],[80.970219,26.870158],[80.971563,26.870375],[80.972621,26.870555],[80.973218,26.870696],[80.973757,26.870857],[80.974296,26.871056],[80.975396,26.871483],[80.975879,26.871687],[80.976287,26.871814],[80.976984,26.871906],[80.982306,26.872209],[80.986702,26.872506],[80.987844,26.872561],[80.989011,26.872636],[80.989813,26.872683],[80.990906,26.872726],[80.992431,26.872787],[80.993893,26.872867],[80.994280,26.872883],[80.994682,26.872976],[80.994945,26.873070],[80.995300,26.873258],[80.995569,26.873483],[80.995714,26.873625],[80.995816,26.873757],[80.996010,26.874107],[80.996091,26.874381],[80.996108,26.874760],[80.996113,26.875464],[80.996104,26.875864],[80.996004,26.877084],[80.995989,26.877489],[80.996010,26.878304],[80.996010,26.879205],[80.996030,26.880229],[80.996041,26.883578],[80.996023,26.884279],[80.995998,26.884601],[80.995930,26.884999],[80.995864,26.885528],[80.995852,26.886171],[80.995857,26.887903]]}}
]
};
```